# I am receiving null pointer exception , when i try to get mylocation from map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-latitude

I am unable to get my location from map , it throws null pointer exception.

```
        if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        try {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFrag)).getMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            putMarkerOnMap(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
        }
```

It throws error at the line .. where i calling a function putMarkerOnMap(lat,lng)
Here is that function

```
    public void putMarkerOnMap(double la , double lo){
    LatLng position = new LatLng(la,lo);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(la, lo)).title("Your Location"));
    CameraPosition campos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(position).zoom(15)
            .bearing(90)
            .tilt(40)
            .build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(campos));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getMyLocation()` is deprecated. So don't use it. Instead use the FusedLocation API provided by the Google Play Services to get the current location.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

Comment: Actually i need the location in fragment.... can i use FusedLocation API in my fragment

Comment: yep it worked with fragment.. there is a problem that.. It is giving me the old location not the updated one where i am now !
whereas i am calling the last known location which is built in function ... IS there any function which give me the current location.. HERE IS CODE 
`    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            putMarkerOnMap(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }
    }`

Comment: Well it is supposed to return the latest location available. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#public-methods) for more detail and choose the method which is most suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think NPE is caused in this line

```
mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude()
```

Also, if you want to get current location you should use different approach such as using Google Play Services or Android built-in library

Google Play Services:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Android built-in library:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html